# JavaScript / CSS to totally remove iframe

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a blog system that have their own ads and things.
I would love to disable them, I followed tutorials and such but nothing works.

Code I use now:

```
iframe {
    visibility: hidden; !important
    height: 0px; !important
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The service you use probably requires you to have the ads visible. If they're giving you a service for free then you **should** keep the ads visible.

Comment: Syntax error in your css, misplaced `;`, `visibility: hidden !important;` and `height: 0px !important;` are correct.

Comment: $('iframeID').remove(); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

You can modify above to either remove the node, or hide the node. I'd prefer jQuery's show/hide methods.

Comment: Oh, It removes the ads. But theres a big gap of spaces where they have been.

Comment: To remove the gap, you need to see how they created it initially. They must have have fixed width/height on it.